# SetCell from tabularray in S column (siunitx) not working?

Tags: siunitx, tabularray

I'd like to get the `\SetCell` command from `tabularray` to work in my tabular. I prefer to write my tabulars with `tabularray` as it can usually save you time and can make configuration easier, but the `\SetCell` does not seem to work as intended.

The *normal* tabular seems to work. I have also tried with non-escaping the `\SetCell` but I only seem to get errors that way. Right now it looks as though the `\SetCell` is not doing anything.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
        % hlines, vlines,
        colspec={Q[si={table-format=3.1},c]*{4}{Q[si={table-format=2.1},c]}},
        }
        \toprule
            & {{{\SetCell[c=2]{c} Technetium}}} & &  {{{\SetCell[c=2]{c} Molybdän}}} & \\ \cmidrule[lr]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
            {{{$\lambda$\,/\,\unit{\nm}}}} & {{{$\phi_1$}}} & {{{$\phi_2$}}} & {{{$\phi_1$}}} & {{{$\phi_2$}}} \\
        \midrule
            663,0 & 12,1 & 14,4 & 13,1 & 16,9 \\
            670,0 & 10,9 & 12,9 & 11,8 & 15,7 \\
            678,0 & 9,1 & 11,4 & 10,3 & 14,6 \\
            684,0 & 8,2 & 10,2 & 9,5 & 13,5 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \sisetup{table-format=2.1}
        \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.1]*{4}{S}}
            \toprule
                & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Technetium} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Molybdän} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
                {$\lambda \mathbin{/} \unit{\nano\meter}$} & {$\phi_1$} & {$\phi_2$} & {$\phi_1$} & {$\phi_2$} \\
            \midrule
                663.0 & 12.1 & 14.4 & 13.1 & 16.9 \\
                670.0 & 10.9 & 12.9 & 11.8 & 15.7 \\
                678.0 & 9.1 & 11.4 & 10.3 & 14.6 \\
                684.0 & 8.2 & 10.2 & 9.5 & 13.5 \\
            \bottomrule
         \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Beispiel]

Comment: Unrelated: You can set row 2 to math mode(`row{2}={mode=math}`). Then you won't need to use `$$` in every column.

Comment: @Imran That's a good point. I was not sure if I could use it here, because of the S-column and because of the `\lambda` in the first cell. But it does indeed work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to place the `\SetCell[c=2]{c}` in front of the triple curly braces. `tabularray` also supports the column type `S`, so you can simplify your `colspec` definition.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx}

\begin{document}
    tabularray\\
    \begin{tblr}{
            % hlines, vlines,
            colspec={S[table-format=3.1]*{4}{S[table-format=2.1]}},
        }
        \toprule
        & \SetCell[c=2]{c}{{{Technetium}}} & & \SetCell[c=2]{c} {{{Molybdän}}} & \\
        \cmidrule[lr]{2-3} \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
        {{{$\lambda$\,/\,\unit{\nm}}}} & {{{$\phi_1$}}} & {{{$\phi_2$}}} & {{{$\phi_1$}}} & {{{$\phi_2$}}} \\
        \midrule
        663,0 & 12,1 & 14,4 & 13,1 & 16,9 \\
        670,0 & 10,9 & 12,9 & 11,8 & 15,7 \\
        678,0 & 9,1 & 11,4 & 10,3 & 14,6 \\
        684,0 & 8,2 & 10,2 & 9,5 & 13,5 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \vspace{1cm}
    
    \sisetup{table-format=2.1}
    tabular\\
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.1]*{4}{S}}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Technetium} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Molybdän} \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
        {$\lambda \mathbin{/} \unit{\nano\meter}$} & {$\phi_1$} & {$\phi_2$} & {$\phi_1$} & {$\phi_2$} \\
        \midrule
        663.0 & 12.1 & 14.4 & 13.1 & 16.9 \\
        670.0 & 10.9 & 12.9 & 11.8 & 15.7 \\
        678.0 & 9.1 & 11.4 & 10.3 & 14.6 \\
        684.0 & 8.2 & 10.2 & 9.5 & 13.5 \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular output]

Comment: Thank you. I was not sure where the triple escape was needed. But it makes sense that the `\SetCell` cmd should not be escape but rather the non-numerical input.